# How to make App Engine Datastore private

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm developing an App Engine app that offers users to keep a diary.
Now, I noticed that I can check all data in datastore through Developers Console.
This is not good for a diary app for privacy.
So I want to know how to make datastore private to prevent me from checking users' data.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little bit tricky since the code can read the data in the datastore and so, by definition, anyone who can update the running code can also read the data in the datastore; however, there are ways that you can at least make it more difficult to inadvertently examine the data (though accessing the data will still be technically possible for you or any of the owners to do). The simplest way is to encrypt the data before storing it within the datastore model objects (and decrypting it when you read the data from the model objects); however, this will make indexed fields no longer work if you do that (you will need to decide whether that content really needs to be indexable or whether it is worthwhile to add manual indexing).

If you want data to not be readable by you at all, then you will need to encrypt/decrypt the data with a key that is only available to your application while the user is interacting with it (e.g. encrypting the data in the client that communicates with your server); however, you need to be aware that this will make any sort of indexing or background processing of the data impossible.

Comment: Everything you say is correct, but encrypting/decrypting data just to hide it from yourself is really weird, not to mention the performance penalty on the application. And what's the point of encryption if a person has access to the key and, in the moment of moral weakness, can always use it to decrypt all the data anyway?

Comment: @Andrei, you can always add extra layers to make it much more difficult to do. For example, let's say you encrypt the standard key with the bootstrap key. Anything not user specific gets encrypted with the standard key. Each user gets a user-specific key, encrypted by the standard key, which is used to encrypt all of that user's information, etc. With enough layers, you can make it so that decrypting data would basically require a custom admin handler, which would allow you to add logging/auditing of the access to the data.

Comment: @Andrei, in terms of moral weakness, you should ensure that only a few, highly scrupulous individuals are listed as owners. It can also help if you have a clear privacy policy and public statements that will have legal repercussions for you should you choose to violate them.

Comment: Again, I agree with everything you say, but this is a case of a single developer writing an app and trying to protect user data from himself :)

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, even with a single developer, there is value in doing this. Privacy, in addition to speed, is an integral feature. It does often make sense to pay the additional overhead of the encryption/decryption to provide greater user privacy.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent you from viewing data in the datastore is to remove you from the developers of the app. A developer can always extract data if he wants to, either by looking it at directly in the Datastore viewer or by writing code that can read/forward this data.